Microsoft Graph API Pagination Issue
I’ve set up an Azure pipeline for the Microsoft Graph API, but the pagination seems to only retrieve 100 rows out of more than 2000 rows. Could someone explain why it’s not fetching all the rows and what might be the mistake here?
The base URL I’m using is: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/
param_relativeUrl with the value: groups$filter=startswith(displayName,'DAP')&$expand=members&$top=999
For pagination, I’ve set the Absolute: none, and the body: {@odata.nextLink}.
Please see the screenshot attached.Activity run
Pipeline created
I'm expecting over 2000 rows.
